# Java Fx styles in css file cannot be hot deployed

Tags: javafx-2

I am creating a desktop application with just `JavaFX` and **CSS** (no Scene Builder). When I run the application in the Debug Mode all `Java` Changes are reflected in the application. But **CSS** changes are reflected only after I restart.
Is there a way to reflect the **CSS** changes also.

Comment: Where are you making the changes to the CSS file, inside the `src` ?

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using? On FX2 you need to reside to internal API to clear the style cache, on FX8 you need to remove and readd the css

Comment: Hi I am using the FX2. And css file resides in src in a package.
I am using a separate css.

Just like the ensemble example.

Comment: @tomsontom - can I use any method to achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around..
It is not a clear solution but it should work.

Suppose I have to hot deploy and change this css

.pop_wizard_Top{

```
-fx-border-width: 5 0 0 0; 
-fx-padding: 10 5 0 0;
```

}

Corresponding Java Code

topPanel = new HBox();

//topPanel.getStyleClass().add("pop_wizard_Top"); - Adding class here

Instead of that write down the styles like below in java class.

topPanel.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 5 0 0 0; -fx-padding: 10 5 0 0; ");

Now we can change the styles.
Once we finalze copy the styles and paste in css.

This is just a work around. !